# Trying to run Kurento remotely on EC2

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kurento

I try to run Kurento on a remote EC2 instance, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how do I load the page up.I have opened all UDP ports, I have configured my kurento server to a STUN server and [checked](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) that it worked but if I run `npm start -- --ws_uri=ws://kms_host:kms_port/kurento` it still says that it's running on localhost.

`etc/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini`

```
 stunServerAddress=74.125.200.127
 stunServerPort=19302

; turnURL gives the necessary info to configure TURN for WebRTC.
;    'address' must be an IP (not a domain).
;    'transport' is optional (UDP by default).
; turnURL=user:password@address:port(?transport=[udp|tcp|tls])

;pemCertificate is deprecated. Please use pemCertificateRSA instead
;pemCertificate=<path>
;pemCertificateRSA=<path>
;pemCertificateECDSA=<path>
```

Now I'm sure I have something wrong with the way I configured it or how I think it's supposed to work. Basically what I want to know is if I want to see the page the kurento hello-world example in the documentation shows but from a remote EC2 instance running kurento, how do I do that because after following their [steps](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#install-kurento-media-server-in-an-amazon-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make kurento work on EC2 is configure coturn server as described in official documentation [here](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#install-kurento-media-server-in-an-amazon-ec2-instance)

If you don't want it, you must find working STUN servers. In my case, on EC2, this server works fine now:

```
stunServerAddress=74.125.142.127
stunServerPort=19302
```